# How to set conditional Gradle properties?

Tags: gradle

I would like to do something like the following:

```
if (System.getenv('JENKINS_URL') == null) {
  org.gradle.daemon = true
  org.gradle.configureondemand = true
  org.gradle.parallel = true
}
```

but the `if` condition seems to be ignored altogether. I've also tried stuff like `org.gradle.daemon = System.getenv('JENKINS_URL') == null`, `org.gradle.daemon = Eval.me("System.getenv('JENKINS_URL') == null")`, `org.gradle.daemon = { System.getenv('JENKINS_URL') == null }()`, and `org.gradle.daemon = "${System.getenv('JENKINS_URL') == null}"` all of which never set the property to true.

Is it possible to have Gradle property settings whose values are conditional?

Comment: Are you putting this in your gradle.properties?

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Hmm interesting, I don't think you can do conditionals or logic in the properties file. You're looking to disable daemon when using jenkins? How about adding `--no-daemon` to your jenkins gradle steps?

Comment: I use a `gradle.properties.ci` that is copied over the `gradle.properties` prior to the gradle build.

Comment: @ben manes, what do you mean by 'copied over'?

Comment: `cp gradle.properties.ci gradle.properties` prior to a gradle build